# How to Drop Indexes on a Table in ArcCatalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-index, oracle-spatial

I am using an Oracle 11g database . The code below doesnt allow me to drop indexes on a table.

```
import arcpy


# Remove indexes and statistics for gis feature class delta tables
COND=r'E:/GISScheduledTasks/DMZGeodatabaseMaintenance/sde/arcfm_synctest.sde/ARCFM.CONDUCTORINFO'
arcpy.RemoveIndex_management(COND,"G190PRIOHCONDUCT;G190PRIOHELECTRI;G190PRIUGCONDUCT;G190PRIUGELECTRI")
print('complete')
```

It gives the attached error.Could someone advise on python coding for dropping indexes on a table within an enterprise database? 
 [image]

Comment: Use List for index name instead of string. ["G190PRIOHCONDUCT","G190PRIOHELECTRI","G190PRIUGCONDUCT","G190PRIUGELECTRI"]

Comment: Please always provide errors as text rather than pictures.

Comment: the List isnt working for me , it gives me an erorr which says " Invalid value for index name or index item"

Comment: How were the indexes created? In Oracle or in ArcGIS?

Comment: Hi, they were created in ArcGIS. but I need to create a script that can first drop them ,  then ill create a the script that would re-add them .

Comment: You may be remove the index recently and didn't create again.you try to remove an index that is not exist. Also test your code in python window (arcmap python window).

Comment: The indexes are well added. It works in the arcmap python window but not in pythonwin(Outside the arcmap python window). I need it to work outside the arcmap python window.